# MySQL rank if empty show blank page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I have a query to display top 5 sellers by day, it works if I want to see the page in a working day because I have items in the tables by this today date, but if I look at the page a sunday I get a entire white page

is there a way to dont get this white page ?

here is a example for the seller top 5 position 3

PHP

```
$datum=date('Y-m-d');
```

MYSQL

```
$tredje= mysqli_query($datacenter, "
SELECT vendedor, total, 
CASE WHEN @l=total THEN @r 
ELSE @r:=@r+1 END as rank,
  @l:=total FROM (select vendedor, 
sum(ventatotal) as total 
from ventas WHERE `fecha` = '$datum' 
group by vendedor 
order by total desc 
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 2 
) totals, (SELECT @r:=0, @l:=NULL) rank;");
```

PHP TO DISPLAY

```
while($dentredje = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tredje))
{
?>
<?php echo number_format($dentredje['total'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

this is the query

Comment: You might want to enable PHP `error_reporting`, its possible that the query or something else is failing hard and halting all PHP execution, rendering then an empty page.

Comment: it only happens when I query in a day without saved items ( non working day ) because there are not sales

Comment: What do you expect to see when there are no matches?

Comment: a 0 should be nice

Comment: a number cero to show no sales

Comment: Count resultset in query and conditionally put your output code. E.g. if count >0 show output else show custom statement

Answer (score 0):

```
if($dentredje)
{
    while($dentredje = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tredje))
    {
        echo number_format($dentredje['total'],0,',','.');
    }
}
else
{
    echo "your Sunday message here.";
}
```